# I found WIFI_SCANNING_SERVICE in android 5.0.2 source but can't use this service

Tags: java, android, wifi

I want to specify frequency (or channel) of wifi for speeding up wifi scanning.

I have studied android 5.0.2 source and found **[android.net.wifi.WifiScanner](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiScanner.java?av=f)** class in the Android API. The comments on this class say that

> This class provides a way to scan the Wifi universe around the device
>   Get an instance of this class by calling
>   Context.getSystemService(Context .WIFI_SCANNING_SERVICE).

But when I try to use this using the following code:

```
Context.getSystemService(Context .WIFI_SCANNING_SERVICE)
```

in Android Studio 1.0 (SDK： android 21 for complie), the IDE hints that there is no such "WIFI_SCANNING_SERVICE" even though it's described in the documentation.

I have also tried `startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested)` in `android.net.wifi.WifiManager` class but I get an error saying "no such function".

This function is documented [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java?av=f)

Please let me know how I can use the above mentioned service and/or function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Context.WIFI_SCANNING_SERVICE` static variable as it is [marked](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/Context.java#Context) as a `@SystemApi`. A system API is not intended to be used by other standard Android apps as described in the comments [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/annotation/SystemApi.java#SystemApi):

> ...These APIs are not guaranteed to remain consistent release-to-release,
>   and are not for use by apps linking against the Android SDK...